# XQuery HTML array input

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db, xquery-3.0

I am new to XQuery 3.0 and trying to write a project.

I am sending a post request containing `song[]` input element.

However, when I try to use `request:get-parameter('song[]', '')`, it gives me a result as below:

```
Value 1 Value 2 Value 3
```

Anyone knows how to get these variables separately?

*Edit: Actual contents of the request parameter being POSTed to eXist is provided.*

**HTML Form:**

```
<form action="post.xq" method="POST">
    <input name="song[]" type="text" value="Song 1" />
    <input name="song[]" type="text" value="Song 2" />
    <input name="song[]" type="text" value="Song 3" />
</form>
```

**post.xq:**

```
let $result := request:get-parameter('song[]', '')
return
    <result>
        {$result}
    </result>
```

**result:**

```
<result>Song 1 Song 2 Song 3</result>
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual contents of the request parameter being POSTed to eXist?

Comment: @joewiz I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours songs are all there, as a sequence of 3 strings. The `$result` variable is a sequence of 3 strings returned by the `request:get-parameter()` function. To access them individually, you can use a positional predicate, e.g.:

```
<result>{$result[1]}</result>
```

To output them all, you could use a FLWOR expression, e.g.:

```
for $song at $n in $result
return
    <song n="{$n}">{$song}</song>
```

Or for simpler uses (assuming XQuery 3.0 is available), the simple map operator, e.g.:

```
$result ! <song>{.}</song>
```

Or for returning the values as a string, separated by, say, a semi-colon, e.g.:

```
string-join($result, "; ")
```

The reason you're seeing them as a single space-delimited string (`Song 1 Song 2 Song 3`) is that the 3 items in the sequence are being normalized, and the default item separator is a single space. For more on sequence normalization and the item separator, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#serdm.

Comment: joewiz saved the day again :)